# Drop element in grid in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to implement drag and drop from panel to grid.

in panel i am doing like this

```
onDrag: function(e) {
    var pel = this.proxy.getEl();
    this.x = pel.getLeft(true);
    this.y = pel.getTop(true);
    var s = this.panel.getEl().shadow;
    if (s) {
        s.realign(this.x, this.y, pel.getWidth(), pel.getHeight());
    }
},
```

Now element is draggable.
But i dont have any idea how to get drop element in grid.
in grid i am trying to use plugin

```
{
    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
    //dragGroup: 'dispatch.scheduler',
    dropGroup: 'dispatchGroup'
},
```

And on in listeners trying to listen drop event 
 But i am not getting any result.

Give me some idea how can i implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?